# Custom method 'REPORT' http request in flutter

Tags: xml, http, flutter, report

I'm trying to accomplish in flutter this REPORT method that I can do in postman:

```
REPORT /remote.php/dav/files/UserName/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.example.com.br
Authorization: Basic d3ByZW******ZWFubmV0
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.17.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 9c6c16ec-355a-408a-a5df-2095499ebfb9,1af9a0e6-641b-446a-9aa1-691ed79faa11
Host: example.example.com.br
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<oc:filter-files  xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:oc="http://example.org/ns" xmlns:nc="http://example2.org/ns">
    <oc:filter-rules>
        <oc:favorite>1</oc:favorite>
    </oc:filter-rules>
</oc:filter-files>
```

But I have no ideia how to add the XML part as a parameter. The closest I've got was with Dio:

```
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  dio.options.method = 'REPORT';
  dio.options.headers = {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: basicAuth};
  Response response = await dio.request("$protocol://$baseUrl/$basePath/$us/");
```

When tested inside 'try/catch' block, returns this:
I/flutter ( 6407): DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error[500]

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `await dio.request("$protocol://$baseUrl/$basePath/$us/", data: '<?xml version... etc');`

Comment: I've tried like that, removed my variables and fixed the values witch work in postman. Putting inside a try, it catches exception...

Comment: What's the exception - update the question

Comment: I/flutter ( 6407): DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error[500]

Comment: check with the server admin why it doesn't like your request

Comment: I would, if the postman gave me the same error, but it works just fine, when I put the xml on the body section.

Comment: Resolved my problem with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399365/flutter-http-request-send-using-xml-body