# Flutter HTTP request send using xml body

Tags: xml, http, flutter, dart, dio

I'm trying to process a HTTP request in Flutter/Dart (in this case using the SEARCH method to filter some files on a WebDAV server (Nextcloud)) need to send XML data in the body of the request.

[x] Can execute the comand using cURL on terminal with the --data parameter:

```
curl -u user:pass -X SEARCH 'https://host123.com.br/remote.php/dav' -H "content-Type: text/xml" --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><d:searchrequest xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:oc="http://owncloud.org/ns"><d:basicsearch><d:select><d:prop><d:displayname/></d:prop></d:select><d:from><d:scope><d:href>/files/wprech</d:href><d:depth>infinity</d:depth></d:scope></d:from><d:where><d:and><d:or><d:eq><d:prop><d:getcontenttype/></d:prop><d:literal>image/png</d:literal></d:eq><d:eq><d:prop><d:getcontenttype/></d:prop><d:literal>image/jpg</d:literal></d:eq><d:eq><d:prop><d:getcontenttype/></d:prop><d:literal>video/mp4</d:literal></d:eq></d:or></d:and></d:where><d:orderby/></d:basicsearch></d:searchrequest>'
```

[x] Also works via Postman app:

[ ] Can't do this request with xml body using Flutter/Dart.
All other HTTP requests of this project we used the DIO pkg, and it works fine, but the problem is. to send the xml body with it. The closest code is bellow:

```
void _list() async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

var us = prefs.getString('id') ?? '';
var sn = prefs.getString('password') ?? '';

String basicAuth = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$us:$sn'));

try {
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  dio.options.method = 'SEARCH';
  dio.options.responseType = ResponseType.plain;
  dio.options.headers = {
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: basicAuth,
    'content-Type': 'text/xml'
  };
  String data =
      '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><d:searchrequest xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:oc="http://owncloud.org/ns"><d:basicsearch><d:select><d:prop><d:displayname/></d:prop></d:select><d:from><d:scope><d:href>/files/wprech</d:href><d:depth>infinity</d:depth></d:scope></d:from><d:where><d:and><d:or><d:eq><d:prop><d:getcontenttype/></d:prop><d:literal>image/png</d:literal></d:eq><d:eq><d:prop><d:getcontenttype/></d:prop><d:literal>image/jpg</d:literal></d:eq><d:eq><d:prop><d:getcontenttype/></d:prop><d:literal>video/mp4</d:literal></d:eq></d:or></d:and></d:where><d:orderby/></d:basicsearch></d:searchrequest>';

  Response response = await dio.request(
      "https://host123.com.br/remote.php/dav",
      data: data);

  print(response);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}}
```

Server responses vary between 400, 404, 500 e 501, depending how it's sent:

```
I/flutter ( 6767): DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [400]
```

Any help? :)

Comment: Have you tried with `package:http`? Make a `BaseRequest` with the correct method, then `send()` it.

Comment: @RichardHeap can't find any example using the package:http and sending xml body and custom methods like 'SEARCH'. Have one?

Comment: No, but it's easy to piece together. (There's nothing special about the body being XML - it's just a string.) Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experiment with a simpler `package:http` version.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main() async {
  var username = 'foo';
  var password = 'B@r!';
  var credential = base64.encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
  var client = http.IOClient();

  var request = http.Request(
    'SEARCH',
    Uri.parse('https://host123.com.br/remote.php/dav'),
  );
  request.headers.addAll({
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic $credential',
    'content-type': 'text/xml' // or text/xml;charset=utf-8
  });

  var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...';
  // either
  request.body = xml;
  // which will encode the string to bytes, and modify the content-type header, adding the encoding
  // or
  // request.bodyBytes = utf8.encode(xml);
  // which gives you complete control over the character encoding

  var streamedResponse = await client.send(request);
  print(streamedResponse.statusCode);

  var responseBody =
      await streamedResponse.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
  print(responseBody);
  client.close();
}
```

Comment: I've used your snippet and now it returns the status code 207, same code returned in postman, that's an advance. How I can turn up the response data as expected? Tried autocompletion on print(streamedResponse.xxxx), but none returns the response body or data.

Comment: `StreamedResponse` autocompletes with a getter called `stream` which is a `ByteStream`. You probably want a string, rather than a stream of bytes, so you have to convert the bytes to characters with a character encoding, and then collect together any parts of the string into one. Answer updated.

Comment: It's finally worked! Can't thank you enough. I will buy you a beer if you're around here . Thanks again.